# Webscraping with rvest advice

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to webscrape a website listed below. I've included my initial code below:

```
library(rvest)

session = html_session("https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder/")

session %>%
  html_form %>%
  .[[3]] %>%
  set_values(search_text = "John") %>%
  submit_form(session, .) %>%
  html_node("table")
```

It doesn't seem to be working at all. Does anyone have some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
page<-html_session("https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder")
details<-rvest:::request_POST(page,url="https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder/engine/",body=list("q"="John"))
s<-jsonlite::fromJSON("ok.json")
df<-as.data.frame(s)
```

You will get usable data frame `df` to use it for further processing

Comment: How did u figure it out? I don't see that form anywhere in the html

Comment: http://imgur.com/D6hsekh

You will be able to see how I found in Network tab of Developer Console in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `table` node in your target page, which you can determine by trying to find something else in the page, e.g.:

```
> session %>% html_form %>% .[[3]] %>% set_values(search_text = "John") %>% submit_form(session, .) %>% html_node("ul")
Submitting with 'pf_search'
{xml_node}
<ul class="menu">
[1] <li class="first leaf go-umass"><a title="" href="https://go.umass.edu/">Go.UMass</a></li>
[2] <li class="leaf email"><a title="" href="//www.oit.umass.edu/email">Email</a></li>
[3] <li class="leaf spire"><a title="" href="https://www.spire.umass.edu/">SPIRE</a></li>
[4] <li class="leaf moodle"><a title="" href="https://moodle.umass.edu/">Moodle</a></li>
[5] <li class="leaf umassonline"><a title="" href="https://uma.umassonline.net/">Blackboard Learn</a ...
[6] <li class="last leaf udrive"><a title="" href="https://udrive.oit.umass.edu/">UDrive</a></li>
```

Comment: yes i was aware. no table means no results meaning the search didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer this way:

```
umass_people_find = function(q)
  "https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder" %>%
    html_session %>%
    rvest:::request_POST(url = "https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder/engine/",
                        body=list("q"=q) ) %>%
    .$response %>%
    httr::content("text") %>%
    fromJSON %>%
    .$Results
```